# Parallel cpu processing tm Dcorpus polarity

Tags: r, parallel-processing, tm

I am trying to examine a data base containing roughly 80.000 txt-documents through the polarity of each sentence in the text with R.

My problem is that my computer isn't able to transform the txt-files into a corpus (12gb RAM, 8 CPUs, Windows 10) - it takes more than two days.

I found out that there is a way to use all CPU's parallely with the DCorpus-function. However, starting with the Dcorpus, I don't know how to run the splitSentence-function, the transformation to a data frame and the scoring via the polarity-function using all CPUs parallely again.

Moreover, I am not sure whether a parallelization of the code helps me with the RAM-usage?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Even if you parrallelise the code you will still have to handle all the data in memory (+ eventually intermediate outputs of your text processing pipeline). What about storing the data in a database (e.g. sqlite) and then process it by smaller chunks (this is usually what I do and it is relatively straightforward to implement).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer Duf59: Well, that's what I've feared. I have to admit that I have never used SQL before - what would be the advantage compared to merely splitting the 80.000 documents into chunks and running the code for each chunk? Does it make a huge difference time-wise if I run chunks instead of the whole data base at once?

Comment: To use sqlite from R without avoid direct interaction: maybe use the PCorpus functionality. I have contributed an answer recently here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823739/r-tm-reloading-a-pcorpus-backend-filehash-database-as-corpus-e-g-in-restart . Strategy: Create a PCorpus, loop over the documents in batches. However I don't know if this approach scales up to 80000 docs, and if it is practical for your problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

All your problems raise from `tm` package usage which is incredibly inefficient.
Try, for example, [text2vec](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec) package. I believe you will be able to perform your analysis in minutes and with very moderate ram usage.
Disclosure - I'm the author of this package.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Correct me if I am wrong, but I can't prcoess sentence based analysis with this package. It's a different approach isn't it?

Comment: Just imagine, that each sentence is a document and you are done. For sentence tokenization use `stringi::stri_split_boundaries(test, type="sentence")`

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks so much. BTW, I went through your package description yesterday - sounds incredibly great. Really excited to try it out.